# Parsing a string in C

Tags: c, string, parsing

I want to parse a string and do some checks on the last character of the string. For example:

```
char *name = "angela";

int i;
for(i = 0; i <= strlen(name); i++) {
    if(name[i] == 'a' && i == strlen(name)) {
        *do something here*;
     }
}
```

I tried this but nothing happens. Why won't this work?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you should call `strlen()` outside the loop and store its value in a variable. It's iterating over the entire string on each call.

Comment: store the value of strlen() instead of processing it every iteration.

Comment: Since name isn't volatile (and isn't getting modified in the loop), it's probable that the calls are all getting optimized down to a single call anyways.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch: Perhaps. I don't know how good optimizers are determining loop invariants.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change:

```
for(i = 0; i <= strlen(name); i++) {
    if(name[i] == 'a' && i == strlen(name)) {
```

to:

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++) {
    if(name[i] == 'a' && i == strlen(name) - 1) {
```

Reason: the first character in a C string, `s`, has index 0, and the last character has index `strlen(s) - 1`, for a total of `strlen(s)` characters.

Comment: Also a fix for `for`: `for(i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++)`

Answer (score 3):

The function strlen returns the actual length of a string, not its last index.
In your example "angela", strlen will return 6 but the last index of this character array is 5. So you have to use:

```
if(name[i] == 'a' && i == strlen(name) -1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just check the last character of the string like this(no need to use a loop):

```
char *name = "angela";
if(strlen(name)>0)//do the check below only if the string is not empty
if(name[strlen(name)-1]=='a')
{
    //do something here
}
```